# 404 page after changing hyperlinks configuration

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, hyperlink

I do not know why i change the configuration of my permalinks from
POSTNAME :http://c51.444.myftpupload.com/sample-post/ to
PLAIN: http://c51.444.myftpupload.com/?p=123
but now i want to change to the previous config but i got a 404 page not found error.
[image: site issue with hyperlinks]

I have researched thru internet and they suggest to modify the permissions of the htaccess file to 666 which I have done already, some just say to go the permalinks options on WP and then click on save button but this did not solve my issue too.

I'm kinda thinking that the real solution is in the htaccess but I really do not know what would be the exact config to use. Here it is my htaccess:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Here is it the staging site where my site is running now: http://c51.444.myftpupload.com/

Thanks in advance for your help

*FYI I got to say that before posting this thread I follow related topics here on stackoverflow but those suggestions I have tried already. I am not sure what exactly to do. Thanks in advance ok

Comment: So as I'm understanding it, everything was working, but when you toggled your permalinks to plain, and then back, they stopped working. If everything was functional before, and no changes were made the .htaccess file, it should be fine still. Your issue may be somewhere else, are you using any caching plugins?

Comment: Can try to add <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @Ryankozak i am using this one: P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler) which makes a report of which plugins slows down the site. but if you are talking about W3 total cache i do not have it installed.

Comment: @VaibhavSoni i added that code on htaccess file and then refresh page but still the same 404 error. DO i have to do something else to make this code work properly. Thanks though

Comment: Under **Settings->General** are your _Wordpress Address_ and _Site Address_ URL correct for the staging domains you're using?

Comment: right now it has the following: http://c51.444.myftpupload.com/
it can not be changed because staging is a functionality Go Daddy provides me to do changes without affecting site in production. Would this be a reason for failing?

Comment: @Ryankozak i have deactivated all the plugins i have and it seems one of them is breakling the hyperlinks. i am going to find out and let u know the rest for the sake of whom experiences the same issue

Comment: @Ryankozak it turns out tobe a problem with gravity forms plugin. I deactivated completelt and then install it and upgrade it to a newest version that fix the whole issue. thanks to all

Comment: awesome, glad to hear you fixed it.

Comment: @Ryankozak post your answer and i will mark it as the solution so u can get some points (Y)